# Track Method Dependencies Via ASM

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to track method dependencies via ASM. For example, lets say I have class like this:

```
class Test{

  public void methodToRun(){
      Depedencies.startTracking();

      //method calls here 

      Depedencies.stopTracking();
  }

}
```

and `methodToRun` is called. Since I have `Depedencies.startTracking()` I need to start printing out all method call details still I see `Depedencies.stopTracking()`.

I tried to do this via ASM with the below code:

```
public class ClassPrinter extends ClassVisitor {
   @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
          MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
          MethodAdapter adapter = new MethodAdapter(mv);
          return mv == null ? null : adapter;
    }
}
```

and then the adapter looks like this:

```
class MethodAdapter extends MethodVisitor implements Opcodes {

    public MethodAdapter(final MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(ASM5, mv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {

        if(name.contains("startTracking")){
            System.out.println("Started tracking")
            TrackerState.startTrack();
        }else if(name.contains("stopTracking")) {
            System.out.println("End of tracking")
            TrackerState.stopTrack();
        }

        if(TrackerState.status())
        {
            //print the details.
        }

        mv.visitMethodInsn(opcode,owner,name,desc,itf);
    }

}

class TrackerState {
    private boolean static track = false;

    public static void startTrack(){
        track = true;
    }

    public static void stopTrack() {
        track = false;
    }

    public static boolean status() {
        return track
    }
}
```

The above ASM code works only for one level method call tracking. Meaning, it doesn't track if a method calls another method ( which I supposed to be track ), below code explains the problem:

```
class Test {
    public void methodRunning()
    {
        Depedencies.startTracking();

        method1() //tracked , but method1's method calls doesnt get tracked
        method2() //tracked , , but method2's method calls doesnt get tracked and so on

        Depedencies.stopTracking();

        otherMethod() // not tracked as expected. 
    }
}
```

how to handle this case via ASM?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you're inserting code into methods, your inserted code will only run in methods you inserted it into.  For example, `method1`'s calls are not tracked because you didn't instrument `method1`.  You may want to look at aspect-oriented tools before implementing your own instrumentation system.

Comment: Wait, do you want to log calls at runtime or just print a static call graph (before runtime)?  (There's probably an existing call graph tool you can use or adapt -- I know Eclipse and NetBeans both have this functionality, so you can look at how they do it.)

Comment: I want to get the static call graph before runtime

Answer (score 2):

If you want to visit the contents of `method1()` and `method2()` you need to visit them separately, using the same technique you used to check `Test`.

If there is any recursion or inheritance going on, that might turn out to be tricky.

In the first case the problem lies in figuring out the stopping condition (to avoid infinite recursion), and in the second, figuring out what concrete implementation of the method to visit.